# Proof of linearity of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

My course problem booklet (mathematics BSc, second year module in algebra, unpublished) has a question (I paraphrase),

> Prove that the operator $D:=x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$ on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is linear.

The first half of the proof in the solution booklet has,
\begin{aligned}
D[f_1(x)+f_2(x)]
& = x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[f_1(x)+f_2(x)\right] && (1) \\
& = x\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f_1(x)]+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f_2(x)]\right) && (2) \\
& = x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f_1(x)] + x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f_2(x)] && (3) \\
& = D[f_1(x)] + D[f_2(x)] && (4)
\end{aligned}

My question is about the step from (2) to (3). What sort of thing is $x$ that it can distribute over $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f(x)]$? For instance, is it a function in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$? Is it an operator in $L(C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))$?

Comment: It is just the function $f(x)=x \in C^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ which will distribute by simple pointwise distributive property: for every $x \in \mathbb R$ the expression $\frac{d}{dx}(f_1(x))$ is just a number, the same for $f_2$ and for $x$ and then $x(\frac{d}{dx}(f_1(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(f_2(x))) = x\frac{d}{dx}(f_1(x)) + x\frac{d}{dx}(f_2(x))$ by distributive law

Comment: @Lukas Can you say anything about the relationship between the statements i) "$f(x)$ is a number" and ii) "$f(x)$ is a function; $f(a)=\text{ev}[f(x)]_{x=a}$ is a number"?

Comment: In my notation, $f$ would be a function and I am using $f(x)$ for the evaluation function at the point $x$. But to be very precise one could make the distinction that you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$; this is a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ (I hope you've already justified this). The definition of $D$ is that for each $f\in V$, $Df:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is the function defined as $(Df)(x):= x\cdot f'(x)$. The usual calculus rules tell us that $Df\in V$, hence $D$ is a mapping $V\to V$. The question is whether it is linear, i.e if for all $c\in\Bbb{R}, f_1,f_2\in V$, we have $D(cf_1+f_2)=cD(f_1)+D(f_2)$? The answer is yes. Why? This is a question about functions, and equality of functions is defined pointwise. So fix any $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Then,
\begin{align}
[D(cf_1+f_2)](x)&= x\cdot (cf_1+f_2)'(x)\tag{i}\\
&=x\cdot \left(cf_1'(x)+f_2'(x)\right)\tag{ii}\\
&= c\cdot x\cdot f_1'(x)+ x\cdot f_2'(x)\tag{iii}\\
&= c\cdot D(f_1)(x) + D(f_2)(x)\tag{iv}\\
&=[c\cdot D(f_1)+ D(f_2)](x)\tag{v}
\end{align}

- (i) is by definition of $D$ acting on the function $cf_1+f_2$, and evaluating that at $x$.
- (ii) is by basic rules of derivatives.
- (iii) is by distributivity and commutativity of multiplication of real numbers (remember that $x,c,f_1'(x), f_2'(x)$ are all just numbers)
- (iv) is by definition of $D$ applied to $f_1$ and $f_2$, and then evaluated at $x$.
- (v) is the definition of scalar multiplication and addition of the functions $c\cdot D(f_1)+ D(f_2)$ is that function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ whose value at any point $x\in\Bbb{R}$  is equal to the number given in (iv).

Finally, looking at (v), notice that we have proved this for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, so by definition of equality of functions, $D(cf_1+f_2)=cD(f_1)+D(f_2)$. Finally, since $c\in\Bbb{R}, f_1,f_2\in V$ were arbitrary, this shows $D:V\to V$  is indeed a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)+g(x))=x\frac{df(x)}{dx}+x\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=D(f(x))+D(g(x))$$

I think you are having trouble because you have not defined how the "operator" acts on a function.

$x\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))=x\frac{df(x)}{dx}$

That is $D(\sin(x))=x\frac{d(\sin(x))}{dx}=x\cos(x)$.

Even more clearly $D(f(x))=xf'(x)$ Now I think it should be clear.

And $D$ is a linear transformation from $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to itself.

That is $D\in L(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$.

Since you tagged as "self learning", let me give you some advice.
The space is $ C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ so actually each smooth "function" is a vector. So it might help if you stop thinking of them as $f(x)$ and write them just as $f$. Now as to what are these functions and what they do....there you need to write as $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=e^{x}$. Going a step further , this $D$ can be thought of also as just a "vector" in $L(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$. That is $D$ is a linear transformation which takes as input a smooth function and gives you back as it's output the derivative of that function times $x$ which is also smooth as multiplication of smooth functions is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is a number, so moving from (2) to (3) is just the simple distributive law.

Answer (score 0):

OP answering own question.

On reflection, it seems to me that there are two different types of $x$ here. As I now see it, the $x$ in $D:=x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$ is a linear operator in $L(C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))$ given by $f \mapsto xf$, while the $x$ in $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ is a number in $\mathbb{R}$.

If we write the argument in the form I used in the OP (call it form A), we have to accept that
\begin{aligned}
& \;\; D:C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \\
\therefore & \;\; \text{for any } f_1,f_2 \text{ that } D \text{ can take as arguments, } f_1,f_2 \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \\
\therefore & \;\; f_1,f_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \\
\therefore & \;\; f_1(x),f_2(x)\in\mathbb{R} \\
\therefore & \;\; \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f_1(x)] = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[f_2(x)] = 0 \\
\therefore & \;\; D[f_1(x)+f_2(x)] = 0 \; \forall \; f_1,f_2 \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}),
\end{aligned}
which is obviously not what we want.

I now write the argument as follows (form B):
\begin{aligned}
\left[D(f_1+f_2)\right](y)
& = \left[x\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(f_1+f_2)\right)\right](y) && (i) \\
& = \left[x\left(\frac{\text{d}f_1}{\text{d}x}+\frac{\text{d}f_2}{\text{d}x}\right)\right](y), \text{ since } \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \in L(C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})) \text{ is linear} && (ii) \\
& = \left[x\frac{\text{d}f_1}{\text{d}x}+x\frac{\text{d}f_2}{\text{d}x}\right](y), \text{ since } x \in L(C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})) \text{ is linear} && (iii) \\
& = [D(f_1)+D(f_2)](y), \text{ as desired}. && (iv)
\end{aligned}

To be fair to the writer of the problem and solution, they used $y_1,y_2$ where I used $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ in the OP. I wanted to write these as functions in order to get at the point that puzzled me.

Comments are welcome, particularly from previous answerers [@Lukas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/844079/lukas), [@5xum](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112884/5xum) and [@Mr.Gandalf Sauron](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/683801/mr-gandalf-sauron)

Comment: Your statement that $x\in L(C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}))$ is strictly speaking wrong. $x$ is just a number, so it is not a linear transformation. WHat you mean is that multiplication by $x$, i.e the mapping $\mu:C^{\infty}\to C^{\infty}$ defined as $[\mu(f)](x):= x\cdot f(x)$ is linear. Most people wouldn't be this nitpicky, and simply say $x$ is a linear transformation, or that "multiplication by $x$ is linear" but since you seem to just be learning this stuff, I think it's a good idea for you to be more precise.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think that's exactly the distinction I've been struggling with. Would you accept that my $x$ as I define it (granted that it may be a confusing choice of notation) is actually the same as your $\mu$? And would you agree that your "by basic rules of derivatives" is (at least in the context) equivalent to my "since $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\in L(C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))$ is linear"?

Comment: Yes, when you wrote $x\in L(V)$, the correct thing to write is $\mu\in L(V)$ (but you have to prove this). Yes, $\frac{d}{dx}= (\cdot)'\in L(V)$, i.e the derivative mapping $f\mapsto f'$ is a linear transformation on $V$ (btw you don't have to say "$\frac{d}{dx}\in L(V)$ is linear"; it's redundant. It is enough to just say "$\frac{d}{dx}\in L(V)$" or "$\frac{d}{dx}$ is linear from $V$ to $V$"). The definition of $D$ is then just the composition $D= \mu \circ \,\,'$, or in more common notation, $D=\mu\circ \frac{d}{dx}$. ANd hopefully you've seen that composition of linear maps is again linear.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks, that's helpful.