# Is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[f(x)]$ defined?

Tags: functions, derivatives

For years I've been in the habit of writing expressions like
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^2) = 2x. \tag{1}
\end{align}

Responses to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384608/proof-of-linearity-of-a-linear-operator) question impressed on me that expressions like $f(x)=x^2$ [Edit: that is, expressions like $f(x)$ or $x^2$; not the specification "$f(x)=x^2 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$"] are function values, not functions, and live in the codomain of $f$. But the domain of the operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is a set of functions, so I now wonder if (1) is, strictly speaking, nonsense, but treated as a convenient paraphrase for
\begin{align}
& \text{Let } f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \text{ be given by } x \mapsto x^2 \; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}; \\
& \text{then } \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}(x) = 2x. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Am I right?

Comment: Did you mean to write "then $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f=x\mapsto 2x$"?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is a function.

Comment: Perhaps the following Math Overflow post is of interest: [If d/dx is an operator, on what does it operate?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115416/if-d-dx-is-an-operator-on-what-does-it-operate).

Comment: @Logic: As mjc points out, it is not $f(x)$ which is the function, but rather $f$.

Comment: @J.G. I didn't intend to write that expression, but I may have intended to express that concept. How is that different from what I wrote?

Comment: The OP is correct. My advice, however, is that you should not take pedants too seriously. If we insisted on keeping the function / function output dichotomy clear, the field of differential geometry would be unreadable.

Comment: "How is that different" - sorry, I didn't notice you'd included the $f$. I must have misread it as $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)=2x$, which is obviously very different!

Comment: @Joe One can represent a function by its range, there is no point in being pedantic about these things, it’s a complete waste of time

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the link. I like Terry Tao's answer, but may not be able to apply it immediately. Following a sequence of links led to other question posts suggesting that this is a question with some depth.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Perhaps you'd be interested in Terry Tao's answer in Joe's link, where he addresses this question from a differential geometry perspective.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw I did that so that Logic's comment, "$f(x)=x^2$ is a function", would still make sense. That comment was also the reason for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question relates to an understanding of [free variables and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). When $x$ is bound, the formula $x^2$ represents a specific value. But when $x$ is a free variable, the formula $x^2$ is more like a function, something which can produce different values depending on what $x$ will be.

The derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ expects a formula with its variable unbound, and produces another function, usually expressed in terms of the same variable. So in most contexts, $\frac{d}{dx} (x^2)$ is fine and will be understood the way you've been using it. However, it doesn't make sense if $x$ is already bound, either by a formal qualifier like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ or its English equivalent "let $x$ be any real value."

There are some related issues with the $\frac{d}{dx}$ notation, though. For example, using it in one classic representation of the chain rule

$$ \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} $$

requires that the $z$ in $\frac{dz}{dx}$ must be considered a function with input $x$, but the $z$ in $\frac{dz}{dy}$ must be considered a function with input $y$, and these are two different functions both "represented" by $z$.

Comment: Thanks aschepler and @Merle for the answers. I'm hestitating to accept one since I don't feel settled on the issue, so I'm not sure if either answer will turn out with further thought to be 'an answer'.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $x$ in the expression $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ is *bounded*. This a concept well-known to programmers, but less so to mathematicians.

For example programmers write $\lambda x:\mathbb N. x + 1$ to mean the function $x \mapsto x +1$. The variable $x$ has no meaning outside of the expression, and $\lambda x:\mathbb N.x +1$ and $\lambda y:\mathbb N.y+1$ are judgementally equal. Hence also $d/dx \,f(x)$ and $d/dy \,f(y)$ denote the same thing, namely the function $f'$.

Yes you are right. $(d/dx \, x^2) \, x = (d/dy\, y^2)\, x = 2x$. You have a similar situation when you work with integrals. The variable $t$ in
\begin{align} \int _a^b f(t)\, dt \end{align}
is bounded. Its scope is only the integral. If you want to substitute an expression which contains one of the bounded variables as a free variable, then you exchange the bounded variable to avoid unintentional capture of variables. Exchanging bound variables is called $\alpha$-conversion in programming and type theory. For example if you have a function in two variables $f$ and you consider the function

\begin{align}
F(x) = \int _a^b f(x,t)\,dt
\end{align}

Assume now you somehow work outside of the integral with the variable $t$ (depending on your context ;), then the correct way to substitute and expression in which $t$ occurs freely is\begin{align} F(\text{some expression in which $t$ is free}) = \int _a^b f(\text{some expression in which $t$ is free},u)\,du\end{align}
and not
\begin{align} F(\text{some expression in which $t$ is free}) = \int _a^b f(\text{some expression in which $t$ is free},t)\,dt\end{align}
because in the second expression the free occurrence of $t$ is unintentionally captured.

If you like to know more about variables and substituting and such, then you should read a text about simply typed lambda calculus!